# preAuthTx - matching transactions

Tags: multi-sig

I have few doubts regarding pre authorized transaction

1. As per the tutorial "Signers of this type are automatically removed from the account when a matching transaction is properly applied". What exactly is matching transaction ? Does that mean transaction need to have same operations and if its payment operation does the payment amount also needs to match ?
2. "In case of error, or when matching transaction is never submitted, the signer remains and must be manually removed using the Set Options operation."
   I assume, this condition is valid only when the other signers of the account have equal or more weight that preauthTx. Is my understanding correct ?
3. Assuming sequence number of account is 5, if I need to create a pre auth transaction, then sequence number should be 7. Because sequence number 6 will be taken by the transaction which will add operations.setOptions.signer(preAuthTx).
   Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. As per the tutorial "Signers of this type are automatically removed
>      from the account when a matching transaction is properly applied".
>      What exactly is matching transaction ? Does that mean transaction need
>      to have same operations and if its payment operation does the payment
>      amount also needs to match ?

<1> Matching Tx:

When someone wants to do a pre-authorized transaction, he generates a hash and supplies the hash to you beforehand. A matching transaction is a transaction having the same hash as pre-supplied.

**The hash changes with every bit of transaction details.** Type of operation has to match; all mandatory and optional fields like tx_seq & amount & memo have to match; every operation in one transaction also has to match.

[YES], "transaction need to have same operations"

[YES], "payment operation needs to have payment amount matching"

---

> 2. "In case of error, or when matching transaction is never submitted,
>      the signer remains and must be manually removed using the Set Options
>      operation." I assume, this condition is valid only when the other
>      signers of the account have equal or more weight that preauthTx. Is my
>      understanding correct ?

<2> "condition is valid only when the other signers of the account have equal or more weight that preauthTx"

[Not exactly]. This operation is ["Set Options", which requires HIGH threshold](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#thresholds). As long as you gain enough threshold to be equal to or more than the high threshold, your operation will be valid.

---

> 3. Assuming sequence number of account is 5, if I need to create a pre
>      auth transaction, then sequence number should be 7. Because sequence
>      number 6 will be taken by the transaction which will add
>      operations.setOptions.signer(preAuthTx). Is my understanding correct ?

<3> Free up some tx_seq #

[YES]. Good that you understand at least one tx_seq has to be reserved for "Set Options"

You may simply [try your ideas at Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) before coding. This helps to prevent the uncertain errors due to coding bug or it being a Stellar feature.